# Is there a way to force an app to output sound through the internal speakers on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, ios

If I use the iPhone in the car while it is parked, and check on the Pokemon Go app, the sound will came out from my car's speakers through Bluetooth, just like the Music app does.

But when I leave the car, is there a way to force the Pokemon Go app to output the sound through the internal speakers of the iPhone?  The Music app does that, but Pokemon Go still tried to output to the car's speakers and it became no audio at all.